# Format issues for ASP/SQL code retrieving numbers from MS-Access Database

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, ms-office, windows-server-2003

I have a local/development website, running on a Windows 2003 server with Office 2003 installed.  I have several ASP pages which extract data from a local MS Access database using pretty normal ASP code:

```
Site = "filedsn=" & Server.MapPath("/" & WebName & "/reffiles/accessdsn.dsn") & ";DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("/" & WebName & "/reffiles/MyDatabase.mdb") & ";DefaultDir="Server.MapPath("/" & WebName & "/") & ";"

set Database = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")

Database.open(Site) 

strSQLMax = "SELECT Format(Max(GetDataRange.Date_Reading),'dd/mm/yy') AS MaxOfDate_Reading, Format(Max(GetDataRange.Speed), '#,###') AS MaxOfSpeed FROM GetDataRange;"

set WeekRecMax = PiDatabase.Execute(strSQLMax)

response.write("<P>Date of Maximum Speed:" & weekRecMax.fields(0).value & " " &  weekRecMax.fields(1).value & " f/hr </P>")
```

When I test code here (I live in France, but the local server is configured with Regional and Language settings for the USA), the results for the above code are:

Date of Maximum Speed: 14 décembre 2016 - 16:03 1 025 f/hr

When I publish my code to our production server in the USA (also Server 2003 with Office 2003) the same page gives this result:

Date of Maximum Speed: 14 December 2016 - 16:03 1,025 f/hr

Of course, the result "1 025" causes other parts of my code to throw an error as it can not be used in calculations.  The space in the "1 025" is actually a "non-breaking space", hex A0.

So my question is: why is this happening and what can I do to this local server to produce output like our USA based production server?

Note, if I change the '#,###' to '####' then the calculations proceed without issues.  Thus, this is not a "show stopper", but it makes me wonder what other surprises may be lurking just around the corner.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Move the formatting of DateTime and Numeric values from the database to asp.net.

```
strSQLMax = "SELECT Max(GetDataRange.Date_Reading) AS MaxOfDate_Reading, Max(GetDataRange.Speed) AS MaxOfSpeed FROM GetDataRange;"

response.write("<P>Date of Maximum Speed:" & Convert.ToDateTime(weekRecMax.fields(0).value).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy") & " " &  Convert.ToDecimal(weekRecMax.fields(1).value).ToString("N0") & " f/hr </P>")
```

The formatting of the values will now be based on the localization, so the code won't break when you use it in the USA.

See more on formatting numbers [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/s8s7t687.aspx).

Comment: Actually, the code breaks when testing locally, runs fine in the USA.  If I understand your comments, you are suggesting that I don't do any formatting in the SQL command, instead do it all in ASP when I'm using the values?  I look at what you suggest. Thanks...

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am suggesting. When you format in SQL you get a string instead of a datetime object. And convertings string back to datetime or decimals etc is always troublesome.

Comment: OK, that works, but in fact my question was really related to "fixing" the local server and not my code.  Any thoughts on that issue?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by fixing the server, but the problem is proably related to Localization so the local server needs to be the same language and language settings as the other server.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I have posted that question in a new thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209841/updating-changing-the-regional-settings-for-all-users-on-windows-server-2003).  Thanks again